# Store multi-byte into char array

Tags: c, unicode

Following code works:

```
char *text = "中文";
printf("%s", text);
```

Then I'm trying to print this text via it's unicode code point which is `0x4e2d` for "中" and `0x6587` for "文":
[image]

And sure, nothing prints out.

I'm trying to understand what's happening here when I store multi-byte string into `char*` and **how to** print multi-byte string with it's unicode code point, and further more, what does it mean by "`Format specifier '%ls' requires 'wchar_t *' argument instead of 'wchar_t *'`"?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:
I'm on Mac osx (high sierra 10.13.6), with clion
[image]

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: maybe you want to specify what compiler you are using

Comment: There needs to be a null terminator for printing strings with `%ls`

Comment: Include header file `<locale.h>`, and add the following line to your main function: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`.

Comment: That warning message is quite confusing. You have found a compiler bug.

Comment: also make sure to include the NULL terminator at the end. Currently you allocated only 2 `wchar_t` which is not enough

Comment: To expand on phuclv's comment, you also need to change `malloc` to `malloc(3 * sizeof(wchar_t))` and assign `arr[2] = 0`.

Comment: Also one _small_ note: when you write _code point_ you actually should say _code unit_ because `wchar_t` holds the _encoded_ value of a code point. On your platform (and Linux in general) `wchar_t` is 4 bytes and encoding is UTF-32 (then they coincide) but on Windows (for example) `wchar_t` is 2 bytes and encoding is UTF-16 and then they differ (because of surrogates). Also note that some Unicode _characters_ are composed sequences [of code points]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>   wchar_t *arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(wchar_t));
>   arr[0] = 0x4e2d;
>   arr[1] = 0x6587;
> ```

First, the above string is not null-terminated. The `printf` function knows the beginning of the array, but it has no idea where the array ends, or what size it has. You have to add a zero at the end to make null-terminated C string.

To print this null-terminated wide string, use `"printf("%ls", arr);"` for Unix based machines (including Mac), use `"wprintf("%s", arr);"` in Windows (that's a completely different thing, it actually treats the string as UTF16)

Make sure to add `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8");` or `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` for Unix based machines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8");

    //print single character:       
    printf("%lc\n", 0x00004e2d);
    printf("%lc\n", 0x00006587);
    printf("%lc\n", 0x0001F310);

    wchar_t *arr = malloc((2 + 1)* sizeof(wchar_t));
    arr[0] = 0x00004e2d;
    arr[1] = 0x00006587;
    arr[2] = 0;
    printf("%ls\n", arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Aside,

In UTF32, code points always need 4 bytes (example `0x00004e2d`) This can be represented with a 4 byte data type `char32_t` (or `wchar_t` in POSIX).

In UTF8, code points need 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes. UTF8 encoding for ASCII characters needs one byte. While `中` needs 3 bytes (or 3 `char` values). You can confirm this by running this code:

```
printf("A:%d 中:%d :%d\n", strlen("A"), strlen("中"), strlen(""));
```

Se we can't use a single `char` in UTF8. We can use strings instead:

```
const char* x = u8"中";
```

We can use normal string functions in C, like `strcpy` etc. But some standard C functions don't work. For example `strchr` just doesn't work for finding `中`. This is usually not a problem because characters such as "print format specifiers" are all ASCII and are one byte.

Comment: Thanks and, having know about the terminator and locale thing and, there was a comment under the question with the link http://utf8everywhere.org and was deleted by the commenter, I have read it and really felt the same way as the authors(I don't want to be an expert in unicode and stuff ;p). So, I'm wondering is it possible to do this trick without using `wchar_t` type but `char` instead?

Comment: You can only show ASCII values with a single character in UTF8. This includes English letters "abcd...", plus formatting characters like `"/\\%,;"` I added some explanation in edit.